# Proof that $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ for closed, connected n-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I believe I could prove it using the universal coefficient theorem, but I also would have to prove that $H_n(M)=0$ if is non orientable, and $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Z}$ if orientable, and then compute the torsion.

Is there a fast way to prove it all, or is there another way to show that $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is single generated?

Comment: The standard argument is a mayer-vietoris type argument on compactly supported cohomology, writing the manifold as a reasonable union of balls and inducting on the number of balls in the union.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are using singular or simplicial homology. For simplicial its quite easy: 
$$\sum \Delta_n$$ the sum of all the $n$ simplices is a generator as is easy to see.

In the case of singular homology one looks at the direct system of groups $H_n(X,X-A)$ for $A$ a compact subset. Every manifold is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ orientable.

Comment: I looked into it. About the simplicial homology, I get stuck due to the boundary. Without boundary, is quite trivial. Since each $n-1$ simplex is border of exactly two $n-$ simplexes, the border of everything is clearly zero, and we cannot have other chains that are not generated by that one. If we have boundary, what happens? Also, how do I pass to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ when I have boundaries?

Comment: With a boundary you look at $H_n(X,\partial X)$. Just $H_n (X)$ must be zero.